# Unable to get the RPC URL to connect MetaMask, When running multiple nodes on single machine in substrate

Tags: rust, ethereum, rpc, metamask, substrate

When running the multiple nodes on the substrate, unable to get the correct RPC URL to connect to MetaMask Wallet

ChainId: 421 at runtime

**Output:**

**Node 1:**

```
2022-07-27 14:32:35 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615
2022-07-27 14:32:35 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9933, allowed origins=Some(["http://localhost:", "http://127.0.0.1:", "https://localhost:", "https://127.0.0.1:", "https://polkadot.js.org"])
2022-07-27 14:32:35 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9945, allowed origins=Some(["http://localhost:", "http://127.0.0.1:", "https://localhost:", "https://127.0.0.1:", "https://polkadot.js.org"])
```

**Node 2:**

```
2022-07-27 14:32:56 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9934, allowed origins=Some(["http://localhost:", "http://127.0.0.1:", "https://localhost:", "https://127.0.0.1:", "https://polkadot.js.org"])
2022-07-27 14:32:56 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9946, allowed origins=Some(["http://localhost:", "http://127.0.0.1:", "https://localhost:", "https://127.0.0.1:", "https://polkadot.js.org"])
2022-07-27 14:32:56 creating instance on iface 192.168.22.183
```

**Steps to produce**
**Node 1 (Command) at terminal 1:**

```
./target/release/frontier-template-node
--base-path /tmp/alice
--chain local
--alice
--port 30333
--ws-port 9945
--rpc-port 9933
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
--telemetry-url 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0'
--validator
```

**Node 2 (Command) at terminal 2:**

```
./target/release/frontier-template-node
--base-path /tmp/alice
--chain local
--alice
--port 30333
--ws-port 9945
--rpc-port 9933
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
--telemetry-url 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0'
--validator
```

Answer (score 0):

From the info provided it is hard to know what "unable to get the correct RPC URL to connect to MetaMask Wallet" means.

But given the command you provided, you cannot use same port to run multiple nodes in single machine and neither you should use same base path to run multiple nodes. This will make both nodes to write to the database and it have no idea that other process is also writing the same file. Instead here is the command you should try:

**run first node**

```bash
./target/release/frontier-template-node
    --base-path /tmp/mynode/alice
    --chain local
    --alice
    --port 3033
    --ws-port 9945
    --rpc-port 9933
    --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    --telemetry-url 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0'
    --validator
```

**run second node**

```bash
./target/release/frontier-template-node
    --base-path /tmp/mynode/bob
    --chain local
    --bob
    --port 3034
    --ws-port 9944
    --rpc-port 9934
    --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
    --telemetry-url 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0'
    --validator
```

Notice the change in port values and base path while running two nodes.

Comment: I tried this solution but its not working